# Selenium / Firefox: Command ".click()" doesn't work with a found element

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find a solution to this thing and I spent a lot of time, but it is almost imposible to me to do that.

The matter: I am using Selenium with Java in Firefox. I need to find an element (a listbox) and click on it. So, the code finds the element, but click action does not work. It works fine in Google Chrome every time, and just sometimes in Firefox (with the same Java code sometimes works, and sometimes does not).

**There is the part of code with the element when the program enters on the page:**

```
    <div id="size-btn" class="size-btn">
      <span class="selected-size">SELECCIONA TALLA </span>
      <div class="size-select" style="display: none;">
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr id="selecsize_2" class="product-size" data-ga-props="{action:'Seleccionar_Producto', opt_label:'Escoger_Talla'}" data-catentryid="1051607">
            <tr id="selecsize_3" class="product-size" data-ga-props="{action:'Seleccionar_Producto', opt_label:'Escoger_Talla'}" data-catentryid="1051608">
            <tr id="selecsize_4" class="product-size" data-ga-props="{action:'Seleccionar_Producto', opt_label:'Escoger_Talla'}" data-catentryid="1051609">
            <tr id="selecsize_5" class="product-size" data-ga-props="{action:'Seleccionar_Producto', opt_label:'Escoger_Talla'}" data-catentryid="1051610">
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <button class="size-guide gaViewEvent gaTrack" data-ga-props="{action:'Seleccionar_Talla', opt_label:'Guia_de_tallas'}" data-href="http://www.anyweb.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductGuideSizeAjaxView?catalogId=24052&categoryId=358056&langId=-5&productId=1047599&storeId=10701">Guía de tallas</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**And there is the part of code that changes when the element is clicked:**

```
    <div id="size-btn" class="size-btn opened">
```

I tried many solutions and sometimes it works, but the next time I run the program, it does not work again.

Some solutions:

1. It finds the element, but does not run click action. I checked with xpath and cssSelector, and there are unique elements found with those expressions.

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='size-btn' and not(contains(@class,'opened'))]/span")).click(); // Also checked with By.cssSelector("span.selected-size")
   ```
2. I though it was because of the time, so I tried to solve it that way.

   ```
   WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='size-btn' and not(contains(@class,'opened'))]/span")); // By.cssSelector("span.selected-size")
   Thread.sleep(3000);
   we.click();
   ```
3. Finally, I was a little bit desperate, and I created a new function to try to do this almost 60 times, looking for the change on the element code and if there was any change, just tried to do click action again.

   ```
   clickAndWaitWhileElementIsNotPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='size-btn' and not(contains(@class,'opened'))]/span"),By.xpath("//div[@class='size-btn opened']/span")); // By.cssSelector("span.selected-size")

   private void clickAndWaitWhileElementIsNotPresent(By by1, By by2) throws Exception {
       for (int second = 0;; second++) {
           if (second >= 60)
               fail("timeout");
           try {
               if (isElementPresent(by2))
               {
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                   driver.findElement(by1).click();
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       }
   }
   ```

There are the images of the element:

[image: Element 1]
[image: Element 2]

Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You need to clarify what "it does not work" means. Is there an exception or what is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: With "it does not work" I mean the expected behaviour of the button is not right, when it clicks on the botton, the drop down list should be open. Thank you.

Comment: had similar issue with select2 dropdowns; 'click' wouldn't work in firefox when trying to click the div - solved by clicking the anchor tag that is injected by select2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finally I found an answer that works with Firefox as well as Google Chrome.

```
WebElement we = this.driver.findElement(By.id("size-btn"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", we);

waitForElementPresent(By.xpath("//div[@id='size-btn' and contains(@class,'opened')]/span"));
```

Comment: Bravo! Works fine! 
I use it with xpath locator, using text from listbox 
_"//*[contains(text(),'23')]"_

Comment: It's almost 2018 and I still have to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why are you using this Xpath, if you have freedom to change Xpath then record the element using selenium IDE and use `Xpath::position` from drop down list of `target`(it picks unique path relative to html header), it will solve problem of dynamic locator. And try below mentioned events.

1- Use `clickAt`.

2- Use `fireevent(focus)` and then click. Sometime it happens some element in back ground is getting loaded, when it gets loaded, focus move there hence elementNotVisible error.

3- Use `mouseDownRight`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that way, but it was not a good solution because this is a dinamic Web.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Firefox. The trick is to click the text inside of  not the button itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have some solution, make a class with a robot put there TAB event keys, then call that class. What it does its like a back to focus to the page. For some razon the page lost focus and never find that botton.

```
   Robot robot;
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    } catch (AWTException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Actions class from org.openqa.selenium.interactions:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("size-btn"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.moveToElement(element).click(element);
builder.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.click(element);
Action action = actions.build();
action.perform();
```

This worked for me.