# Using selenium to get element by id in python testing

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

In my html code below:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="b-menu-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">


                        <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Sign In</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/accounts/signup/">Sign Up</a></li>


                        {% if request.user.is_authenticated or logged_in %}
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b class="caret"></b></a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/accounts/manageAccount/">Manage Account</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/accounts/createProfile/">create profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/accounts/viewProfile/">view profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/accounts/editProfile/">edit profile</a></li>  
                                <li><a href="/accounts/logout/" id="logout">Log out</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>


                        <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#my-modal-box" class="active">
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

I want to select the logout button which is actually appears in a selector in my nav bar.

I tried getting element by name , id etc but nothin worked out.

```
elem2 = self.driver.find_element_by_id("logout")
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I explicitly added id in a href link for logout , but could not grab the element. Any suggestion how can I get the logout element

I get below exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"logout"}' ; Stacktrace: 
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpPHM5S7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8905)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpPHM5S7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8914)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpPHM5S7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10884)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpPHM5S7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10889)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpPHM5S7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10831)
```

Comment: Try `elem2.click()` ?

Comment: Din't work , check my edit to see the exception.

Comment: Is this a template page ? Ie: `{% if request.user.is_authenticated or logged_in %}` ? Perhaps try this test on a served page ?

Comment: Try `print self.driver.page_source` ?

Comment: this code is part of template page

Comment: NoSuchElementException usually appear when element is not found, are you sure you're opening correct page. try print page source first and check it

Answer (score 0):

Got this from [Selenium / Firefox: Command ".click()" doesn't work with a found element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294630/selenium-firefox-command-click-doesnt-work-with-a-found-element)

```
def javascript_manual_click(driver, element_id):
    we = driver.find_element_by_id(element_id)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", we)

javascript_manual_click("logout")
```

Comment: elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) , this actually clicks if it is a button.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Select from UI Support (class selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select(webelement))?

I don't known Python well so my example is in Java:

```
    WebElement dropDownMenu = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']");
    Select logout = new Select(dropDownMenu);
    logout.selectByVisibleText("Log out");
```