# Selenium .NET Click() not working

Tags: .net, selenium, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to click on a standard HTML button.  The driver is locating the element correctly and the `Click()` method completes without exception but the click isn't being invoked on the browser.

The example below just opens the Google homepage and clicks (or fails to click) the *I feel lucky* button.

```
private static readonly InternetExplorerOptions INTERNET_EXPLORER_OPTIONS = new InternetExplorerOptions
{
    IgnoreZoomLevel = true
};

[Test]
public void Clicking()
{
    using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(INTERNET_EXPLORER_OPTIONS))
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnI")).Click();

        Assert.That(driver.Url, Is.EqualTo("https://www.google.com/doodles"));
    }
}
```

I'm using the 32-bit version of `IEDriverServer.exe`.

I'm using IE version `11.576.14393.0`.

Update version: `11.0.38`.

The other solutions have the same (non) affect, however, I have found a useful `wait` condition `ElementToBeClickable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium / Firefox: Command ".click()" doesn't work with a found element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294630/selenium-firefox-command-click-doesnt-work-with-a-found-element)

Comment: Regardless of the browser, sometimes selenium cannot click a found element. One option is to try doing that via Javascript, using `JavascriptExecutor `. You could also try, to test, put some time to wait before clicking, because it may happen due to racing conditions in the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable` wait condition solved the problem.

```
[Test]
public void Clicking()
{
    using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver())
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

        var button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnI"));
        Assert.That(button.TagName, Is.EqualTo("input"));

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(button));
        button.Click();
        wait.Until(webDriver => webDriver.Url == "https://www.google.com/doodles");  // <==  wait until condition here
        Assert.That(driver.Url, Is.EqualTo("https://www.google.com/doodles"));
    }
}
```